# Pygame.draw.circle issue [Python 3.3]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still pretty new to python and have been trying to learn it in my spare time. I'm starting a new project, using pygame, and I was using the draw function to start laying out my UI. here is the total code:

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1080, 720])
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def Mainloop():


   while 1:

        Clock.tick(60)


       for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                pass

        screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
        pygame.draw.line(screen, [0, 0, 0], [0, 520], [1080, 520], 8)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, [0, 0, 0], [750, 0], [750, 520], 8)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, [0, 0, 0], [200, 260], 80, 8)
        pygame.display.flip()


Mainloop()
```

The problem is that no matter what thickness I set my circle to, it's black outline is sprinkled with white pixels. I just want a solid black outline on my circle. I'm sorry if this is stupid but I have been unable to find anything on this specific issue.

Thank you in advance for the help.

EDIT: Here is a pic of of the screen I am getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MR6b.jpg  (It was cropped some though)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't fix this problem. I think this is actually a glitch in pygame itself, because I've checked your code and there's nothing wrong with it. I even went and drew my own circle with pygame and the same problem persisted with me too. I also noticed that these 'white sprinkles' are whatever colour the background  is. Because this is an error in pygame itself, either the creator is going to have to do something about it or you will. Now I'm not too experienced with this kind of thing but what I know for a fact that it will be no easy task. If you ever need a thick circle for whatever reason, then I would make it using something like GIMP or Photoshop then transfer it as an image in pygame- or like I said you could find a way to fix this poblem by looking at the pygame source code, but it's no easy task for a beginner.